# codeigniter mysql 'select' query returns only one column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i try to get values from 3 colums of a table, but the query only return one. can someone help me on this issue?

The model

```
public function get_Forfait($selected_visiteur_np, $selected_mois) {

  $query = $this->db->select('quantite', 'mois', 'idFraisForfait', 'idVisiteur')
    ->from('lignefraisforfait')
    ->where('idVisiteur', $selected_visiteur_np)
    ->where('mois', $selected_mois)
    ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

The controller

```
if ($this->input->post("submitMois")) {
  $selected_mois = $this->input->post('ficheFrais_mois');
  //var_dump($selected_mois);
  //die('ok');
  $this->visiteur_model->get_Forfait($selected_visiteur_np, $selected_mois);
  $this->visiteur_model->get_HorsForfait($selected_visiteur_np, $selected_mois);

  $data['forfait'] = $this->visiteur_model->get_Forfait($selected_visiteur_np, $selected_mois);
  $data['horsForfait'] = $this->visiteur_model->get_HorsForfait($selected_visiteur_np, $selected_mois);
  $data['resultat'] = $this->load->view('visiteur/v_listeFraisValides', $data);

  var_dump($data['forfait']);
  die('ok');
}
```

this is the result of the var_dump. only the column "quantite" is retrieved

```
array (size=104)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[259282]
    public 'quantite' => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[259281]
    public 'quantite' => string '454' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[259280]
    public 'quantite' => string '4' (length=1)
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [***docs***](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) your `select()` function should be

```
$this->db->select('quantite,mois,idFraisForfait,idVisiteur')
```

All select fields should be passed as first argument of `select()` separated by comma not each field as separate parameter